# Calculate $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\frac{a^x+b}{\ln\ln(x+1)}=\ln\ln5$

Tags: calculus, limits

Given the limit:

$$\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\frac{a^x+b}{\ln\ln(x+1)}=\ln\ln5$$
where $x$ - real number, $a,b$ - constants and $a>0$. I should calculate $a-b$.

I tried a lot with using different types of factoring like making nominator $a^x+b=\ln\ln{e^{e^{a^x+b}}}$;$\lim\limits_{x \to 0}{a^x+b} = \lim\limits_{x \to 0}{\ln\ln(x+1)\ln\ln5}$,  but I think I am in a wrong way. Is there any way to solve such limits?

Comment: Can you use the rules of L'Hospital?

Comment: This limit cannot equal $\ln{(\ln{(5)})}$ - see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series+expansion+of+%28a%5Ex%2Bb%29%2Fln%28ln%28x%2B1%29%29+about+x%3D0)

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner, I think differentiation only makes it difficult.

Comment: @PeterForeman, thanks, I understood that it is impossible to happen. Actually, this was given by one university sample questions. So, I tried to solve one by one and stuck in this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can't happen.  As $x \to 0$, 
$$ a^x + b \sim 1 + b + x \ln(a) $$
while as $x \to 0+$,
$$ \ln \ln(x+1) \to -\infty$$
so the left side must go to $0$.